# Move back to previous Activity from another Activity, don't know where Activity is in stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have a `TabActivity` that is the "base" `Activity` in my application.  From the `TabActivity` a user can navigate through new Activities that are not a part of the original TabHost (I'm not messing around with TabGroups or anything like that).

My application also has a global options menu, from which a user should be able to navigate back to the original `TabActivity` and select a certain tab.  For example, if the user selected the left-most options menu item, they would go to the left-most tab in the original `TabActivity`.

How can I accomplish this behavior?  I do *not* want to start a new `TabActivity` because the original `TabActivity` has data propogated on it like Map points and a ListView.  Ideally I would like to go back to that specific `TabActivity`.  This movement can also occur at any point in the lifecycle, e.g.:

Original `TabActivity` -> Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Activity3 -> Activity *n* ->Back to Original `TabActivity`

Original `TabActivity` -> Activity1 -> Back to Original `TabActivity`

There can be any number of Activities launched in between the navigation.  Therefore, calling `finish()` in the current Activity won't satisfy this (as far as I know...).

My questions/concerns:

1. Primarily, how to accomplish this.
2. It *is* possible that the original `TabActivity` could be removed from the stack due to memory, correct?  If so, how to deal with that?  I assume if I figured out a way to locate the original `TabActivity` I could just do a check for null and if it's not there, start a new `TabActivity`.

Comment: Exact question for my current scenario!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out.  You should use `launchMode="singleTask"` in your Manifest for the specific `Activity` that you wish to switch back to.  According to the [Dev docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes) this routes back to that specific `Activity` if it exists.

So, in my Manifest, I have:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainTabsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
```

Then, in any `Activity` where you want to switch back to that `TabActivity`, just call a normal `Intent`.  You can also use `putExtra()` to tell the `TabActivity` to switch to a new tab.

In a sub Activity:

```
        Intent mainTabsSearchIntent = new Intent(this, MainTabsActivity.class);
        mainTabsSearchIntent.putExtra("tabval", 0);
        startActivity(mainTabsSearchIntent);
```

This will either launch a new `MainTabsActivity` if the stack doesn't have one or switch back to the old instance because of the `launchMode="singleTask"` parameter.

In order to provide the tab switching functionality, override `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` in your main `TabActivity` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.d(MyApplication.TAG, "Bringing this Activity back!");

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(extras.getInt("tabval"));
        Log.d(MyApplication.TAG, "Switching to tab " + extras.getInt("tabval"));
    }
}
```

I hope this helps somebody that has a similar problem.

Comment: Wow! Just adding a single line in the Manifest `android:launchMode="singleTask"` helped me out. Thanks `Rockmaninoff`! I've been searching for more than an hour for this.